# send customized event to another iPhone application?

Tags: ios

In iphone application, we can set handlers for system events like call status change (CTCallCenter.callEventHandler), so our application will be notified when calls incoming/dialing/connected/disconnected etc.

I wonder if it's possible for myself to define an event, and let another app to subscribe.

I did some search and found it might be possible on Mac, by using AppleEvents http://hintsforums.macworld.com/showthread.php?t=112964 。However, I guess it might not apply to iOS.

Any ideas?

(I had thought about using openURL, but the problem is I don't want to launch the other application's UI. I only want it to know something happens. I used some tricks to make my other app run in background for long.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No this is not possible, all app run within a sandbox and can't communicate with other app.
You are able to start other app if they have aan App URL scheme defined. With such a scheme you are able to pass parameters.